# Unable to retrieve or download PDF/JPG files from database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am unable to retrieve or download PDF/JPG files from sql server. When i click the button in the browser, it does not respond and nothing happened. Kindly help me. Please check that, is there any problem with the code. 
i have a table that contains id as an integer and

[image]
[image]

and code behind:

```
protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery = "select Upload_Name, Content_Type, Uploads from Tab_CPD_Hours WHERE id =@id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            download(dt);
        }
    }

    private void download(DataTable dt)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Uploads"];
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["Content_Type"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + dt.Rows[0]["Upload_Name"].ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

public static DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's returning nothing, because you're catching all errors and returning null...

```
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

And the method that gets the data, does nothing when a null is returned...

```
DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
if (dt != null)
{
    download(dt);
}
```

You need to handle the error properly, by showing an error message to the user...

Comment: there is no error, i have checked its is not catching any error... while debugging its goes till the end of the program after that nothing happened... i need help :/

Comment: yes ..This was the reason i solved it yesterday.. But thank you so much for the help. :)